# Is it possible to send javascript request using wiselinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

By default rails (I am using rails 4) sends data-remote requests with the following header:

```
Accept:*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript
```

Later in rails code I respond to it using format.js.

I want to migrate to wiselinks, but all data-push requests try to render html.
Is it possible to have default rails behaviour with wiselinks?

Comment: Can you please clarify?  Have you already installed wiselinks and all data-push links still return html?  Or are you asking about how to install wiselinks correctly?

Comment: @manishie, I installed wiselinks as well as changed data-remote to data-push. I just need to change wiselink accept header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don't unserstand correctly how Wiselinks work. If you use `:data => { :remote => true }`, then you simply don't need `:data => { :push => true }`.

Pushing should be used only if you need to update your URL (follow a link).

Comment: I am happy with :remote => true. However it doesn't handle navigation correctly. So I decided to switch to wiselinks. I need JS response because I need to return Js from server which will update several places on webpages.

Comment: Then you can subscribe to `page:done` event. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I rewritten my controllers to respond to html AJAX requsets instead of using JS requests.
This way I can use wiselinks and it works. Main reason I was using JS response is to set page title with javascript and some other details. But with wiselinks I can use special helper for that.

I think there may be a need in the future to implement some complex behaviour after AJAX request, which will require some JS execution on client side after the response. However this will be possible to implement with page:done event

Thank you all for the help!